# How to make trained neural networks with nondeterministic output?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to figure out how to train a neural network to play a puzzle game, given no prior knowledge of the rules. I've previously used neural networks as classifiers, but they're essentially deterministic once trained. This is fine for action games like Mario, but there's a starting problem with a puzzles or games like go or chess where the initial setup is always the same. If the network's first attempt produces an illegal move, the board won't change, so a deterministic system will just keep trying the same illegal move.

Are there particular methods people use to make such a network try different outputs if the first is rejected? I considered having "number of moves" and/or "number of illegal moves blocked" inputs, to give a sense of time, but presumably there are more sophisticated techniques out there!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

In your case, you would need to use techniques that come from reinforcement learning such as Deep Q learning. Indeed, these techniques are not deterministic and learn a policy that is not deterministic. The policy will first integrate the rules of the game to eventually choose a strategy that maximises the payoff. Of course, the environment will have to be properly defined for these methods to be effective.